# SmtpClient hangs with no exception thrown if wrong port was specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I was trying to send emails in my Asp.Net C# application using port 465 with host "smtp.gmail.com" but the whole application hangs (keeps loading). When debugging it's stuck at SmtpClient.Send(msg).

Regardless of the credentials specified, it doesn't throw any exceptions to catch or any timeout errors. I have to close or refresh the page to regain access to the page.

If I put port 587 instead then every thing works fine and the SmtpClient.Send responds and sends the email or returns a proper exception such as operation timeout or failure sending email based on the credentials.

I simplified the code below for demonstration:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
                        {
                            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                            Port = 465,
                            EnableSsl = true,
                            Timeout = 200, // or any value it doesn't solve the problem
                            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name@gmail.com", "password")
                        };

var msg = new MailMessage("name@gmail.com", "name@gmail.com", "Any subject", "Any body"); 
smtp.Send(msg); // stuck here
smtp.Dispose(); // never reached
msg.Dispose();
```

I tried SendAsync and reduced the timeout interval but this did not solve the problem. I think the problem is that smtp.gmail.com was reached but did not respond properly to port 465 and that's why the method was stuck.

I need to avoid such behavior since my application allows dynamic settings of the smtp server details and I don't want the whole application to hang in case of wrong details were entered.

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: Weird, I've never had a problem and it looks right.  Sounds kind of like this problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/99d6812c-9efe-4d0c-94d0-493c688450f7/, but I dont' think he really had a solution there. Can you send outbound on your network using any other application?

Comment: `using (var smtp = ...)` and `using (var msg = ...)`

Comment: @devshorts I captured the TCP traffic only using Wireshark, is this enough?

Comment: @AustinSalonen I tried wrapping it as you suggested using (smtp) { using (msg) { smtp.Send(msg); } } but it did not work, the problem is not related to disposing the objects, it's stuck at the Send command.

Comment: I know.  That's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: set in port=25, it may work

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmtpClient Timeout doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467476/smtpclient-timeout-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3):

Found this answer in case anyone gets here

[SmtpClient Timeout doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467476/smtpclient-timeout-doesnt-work)

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect("192.168.1.180", 25, null, null);
// Two second timeout
bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000, true);
if (!success) {
    socket.Close();
    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to connect server.");
}
```

Comment: what do we do if it is a success, ie how do we send the msg via this socket?

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your SmptClient in a `using` statement, to ensure that Dispose is called.

I'm not sure if this is the cause or your problem or not, but I was having the same issues (sent correctly the 1st time, and often fails afterwards) at this has rectified it for me.

Comment: `Dispose` will never be called if `Send` hangs.